# Execute <Plug> commands in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've recently found a vim plugin using something called `<Plug>`. For example there is a command `<Plug>abc_def` which I would like to execute.

I've tried everything like `:<Plug>abc_def` and similar. Nothing worked. And `:help <Plug>` gave no information.

However, I've been able to execute it by creating a mapping `:map x <Plug>(unite_redraw)`. Then I can execute it by pressing `x`.

Now, is there any way to execute `:<Plug>abc_def` without creating a dummy mapping just to run it? The actual plugin I use is Unite.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`<Plug>` mappings are *meant* to be mapped and called via the map. A `<Plug>` map is a device to expose a clean interface of *plugin actions* to the user.

---

**Example:** Instead of mapping some key to some plugin function in the plugin's hard code, such as "map `zz` to the action 'center cursor aesthetically'":

```
nnoremap <expr> zz 'zz'.float2nr(winheight(0)*0.1).'<C-E>'
```

it is better to expose only a named `<Plug>` mapping from the plugin:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Plug>NiceCenterCursor 'zz'.float2nr(winheight(0)*0.1).'<C-E>'
```

that the user can then remap in their config, without having to copy and paste the "action":

```
nmap zz <Plug>NiceCenterCursor
```

This is then easy to override, reuse, plug into by the user.

---

`<Plug>` mappings are active only in the modes they have been defined for. To execute a `<Plug>` mapping that is defined for normal mode, you can do as with any normal command: use `:normal` (without the exclamation mark).

```
:execute "normal \<Plug>NiceCenterCursor"
```

Since `<Plug>` actually represents a special magic key, we need to use `:normal` together with `:execute` and escape the `<Plug>`.

The `<Plug>` mechanism is described in depth at [`:h 41.11`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#41.11). See also [this article about this topic by a Vim master](http://whileimautomaton.net/2008/09/27022735).

Comment: Oh, so it's essential that the `nmap` is `nmap` and not `nnoremap`, because it will think of `<Plug>NiceCenterCursor` as just another mapping. Correct?

Comment: @Tarrasch Exactly, the right-hand side of the map must be remapped for this to work. Same with `:normal`: it's essential to use the (remapping) `:normal`, not the non-remapping `:normal!`.

Comment: The specific part about `<Plug>` is [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html#using-%3CPlug%3E).

Comment: Thanks for your post! But, how is it compare with create a command?